# проверить число (от 10 до 999 999) на то повторяются ли цифры в нем

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Задание следующее - проверить число на то повторяются ли цифры в нем. Если цифра встречается не более 2 раз - все ок, выводит цифру что повторяется, но если например ввести 999999, выведет 9,9,9,9,9. Хотелось бы понять как можно это сделать. Заранее спасибо

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, k{ 0 }, count = 0;
    int sign[6] = {};

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number between 10 and 1 000 000: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num < 10 || num > 999999 || cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            cout << "\nOops, you`ve entered invalid number. Try again";
        }
        else break;
    }


    if (num >= 10 && num < 100)
    {
        for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i /= 10)
        {
            sign[k] = (num / i) % 10;
            k++;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                cout << "\nYou`ve entered: " << sign[k];
            else
                cout << sign[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
        {
            if (sign[k] == sign[k + 1])
                cout << endl << sign[0] << " = " << sign[1];
        }
    }
    else if (num >= 100 && num < 1000)
    {
        for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i /= 10)
        {
            sign[k] = (num / i) % 10;
            k++;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                cout << "\nYou`ve entered: " << sign[k];
            else
                cout << sign[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            if ((sign[k] == sign[k + 1]) && count == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nNumbers that occur more than once: " << sign[k];
                count++;
            }
            else if (sign[k] == sign[k + 1])
                cout << ", " << sign[k];
        }
    }
    else if (num >= 1000 && num < 10000)
    {
        for (int i = 1000; i >= 1; i /= 10)
        {
            sign[k] = (num / i) % 10;
            k++;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                cout << "\nYou`ve entered: " << sign[k];
            else
                cout << sign[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            if ((sign[k] == sign[k + 1] || sign[k] == sign[k + 2]) && count == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nNumbers that occur more than once: " << sign[k];
                count++;
            }
            else if (sign[k] == sign[k + 1] || sign[k] == sign[k + 2])
                cout << ", " << sign[k];
        }
    }
    else if (num >= 10000 && num < 100000)
    {
        for (int i = 10000; i >= 1; i /= 10)
        {
            sign[k] = (num / i) % 10;
            k++;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                cout << "\nYou`ve entered: " << sign[k];
            else
                cout << sign[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            if ((sign[k] == sign[k + 1] || sign[k] == sign[k + 2] || sign[k] == sign[k + 3]) && count == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nNumbers that occur more than once: " << sign[k];
                count++;
            }
            else if (sign[k] == sign[k + 1] || sign[k] == sign[k + 2] || sign[k] == sign[k + 3])
                cout << ", " << sign[k];
        }
    }
    else if (num >= 100000 && num < 1000000)
    {
        for (int i = 100000; i >= 1; i /= 10)
        {
            sign[k] = (num / i) % 10;
            k++;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                cout << "\nYou`ve entered: " << sign[k];
            else
                cout << sign[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
                if ((sign[k] == sign[k+1] || sign[k] == sign[k+2] || sign [k] == sign[k+3] || sign[k] == sign[k + 4]) && count == 0)
                {
                    cout << "\nNumbers that occur more than once: " << sign[k];
                    count++;
                }
                else if (sign[k] == sign[k + 1] || sign[k] == sign[k + 2] || sign[k] == sign[k + 3] || sign[k] == sign[k + 4])
                    cout << ", " << sign[k];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не пойму ваши навороты...

Вам надо что-то вроде этого? Есть ли цифры, которых в числе больше 2?

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int dig[10] = {0};
    while(n)
    {
        dig[n%10]++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (dig[i] > 1)
            cout << "Digit " << i << " occurs "
                << dig[i] << " times\n";
}
```

Comment: По сути да, суть кода та же. Спасибо. Так увлекся идеей, что не разглядел простого решения